# Why can we undelete our answer on question marked as duplicate?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I answered a question but realized that my question is incorrect that I can't even afford to let it stay there while I fix my question. So I deleted it. When solved the issue, I got back to my answer, edited it *(at that time the question was marked as duplicate)*. I undeleted the question successfully. I think it is a bug that we are allowed to undelete our answer on question marked as duplicate.

Comment: Looks like intended behavior. But... yes it's quite unintuitive.

Comment: @user202729 Look if you have any answer on duplicate question. Delete and undelete it.

Comment: Note that it's allowed to post an answer to a question put on hold in about 4 hours (if you don't refresh the page)

Comment: So far [628](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/895590) cases where this loophole has been used. I don't think that warrants high-priority in closing this *loop-hole*.

Comment: While this might be intuitive, I don't think this is a bug. Closure only prevents additional answers, but doesn't and never prevent answer (un)deletion because the answer is already there (you only soft delete the answer, not hard delete it)

Comment: @Vega No. I didn't answer my own question.

Comment: @BlackThunder could you please check usage of "question" and "answer" in this post? It is very confusing what actually happen...